# Rounding products prices in magento?

Tags: price, rounding

I create a new product and type price= $1.2222. But when I click Save and Continue edit the price = $1.22. I don't want to round the price, i want the price=$1.2222. How can I do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's because of Mage_Core_Model_Store->roundPrice($price)

```
/**
 * Round price
 *
 * @param mixed $price
 * @return double
 */
public function roundPrice($price)
{
    return round($price, 2);
}
```

I've created a module which rewrite core/store and overrides the roundPrice() and has the round($price, 4) inside.

Comment: Thank you but where can I edit that code?

Comment: I told you the class name. Search for it. But don't edit the core. At least copy the file in the app/code/local folder keeping the path.

Answer (score 0):

This is a "feature".
Everything happens because of the input renderer for the price attributes. The `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Helper_Form_Price` class is used to render the price inputs.
At the end of the class there is this method:

```
public function getEscapedValue($index=null)
{
    $value = $this->getValue();

    if (!is_numeric($value)) {
        return null;
    }

    return number_format($value, 2, null, '');
}
```

This makes the prices show with only 2 decimals even if in the db there are 4 of them.
I guess you have to override this method and replace

`return number_format($value, 2, null, '');`

with

`return number_format($value, 4, null, '');`

Comment: Thank you but where can I edit that code?

Comment: I told you the class name. Search for it. But don't edit the core. At least copy the file in the `app/code/local` folder keeping the path.