# Wrong Shipping cost calculation and rounding error on checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-tax

if you add [this product](http://webshop.dagelijksegedachte.net.testbyte.nl/het-kleine-boekje-van-de-dalai-lama.html) (for example) to the card on the `/checkout/cart/` page the Shipping cost are wright €2.95

But in the checkout page `/onestepcheckout/` the Shipping cost are €2.96 (wrong).

How do i get it also €2.95 here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace the contents of
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/onestepcheckout/summary.phtml
with [this content](https://gist.github.com/speedupmate/5f8b1c20f88b0bbfcc61), this will solves the issue.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60353/rounding-products-prices-in-magento) can help you too a bit.