# Magento1: Round the price of products in complete site?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price, rounding

I have 1200 products and all have prices like `12.99`, `69.65`, `55.24`  etc. I want to round the price in my complete site everywhere so that functionality will not break and it will display rounded price in frontend.

Tell me any possible and easy way to round prices of products.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60353/rounding-products-prices-in-magento You can use round() function

Comment: I need to override this function. So , on checkout page , default it will display round prices right ???

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. Please explain what you mean by "functionality will not break". Do you still want to sell the products for like 12.99 but show rounded prices everywhere? (that sounds like you might get into legal trouble, but I don't know where you are located) Or do you want to sell them for the rounded prices? Do you still need the original prices?

Comment: i want to sell them for rounded prices but i don't want to change my 1200 product prices.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding products prices in magento?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60353/rounding-products-prices-in-magento)

Answer (score 0):

Extends core model Mage_Directory_Model_Currency and paste the below code.

```
public function convert($price, $toCurrency = null) {
    if (is_null($toCurrency)) {
        return $price;
    } elseif ($rate = $this->getRate($toCurrency)) {
        $priceValue = $price * $rate;
        $priceValue = $this->_roundPrice($priceValue);
        return $priceValue;
    }
    throw new Exception(Mage::helper('directory')->__('Undefined rate from "%s-%s".', $this->getCode(), $toCurrency->getCode()));
}
protected function _roundPrice($price) {
    return $roundedPrice = round($price);
}
```